# how to store value against array index in state reactjs

Tags: arrays, reactjs, use-state

```
const addProductCart = (value, key)=>{
    cartProducts[key] = value;
    const tempCart = [...cartProducts, setCartProduct(cartProducts)]
    tempCart.splice(key, 1)
    setCartProduct(tempCart)
    
}
```

this is my code block , i want to set value against key in setCartProduct

Comment: can you please elaborate here, what you are trying to do in above codeblock? and example on how u need to store your data?

Comment: i am getting two arguments in addProductCart(value, key), i want to store the "value" (first argument of the function) on index "key "  (which is the second argument of the function) in a array state

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like following:

```
const addProductCart = (value, key)=>{
    // cartProducts[key] = value;
    // const tempCart = [...cartProducts, setCartProduct(cartProducts)]
    // tempCart.splice(key, 1)
    const tempCart = cartProducts.map((product, index) => index === key ? value : product)
    setCartProduct(tempCart)
}
```